# How to sort array of object based on div position

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML list with rearrangable divs, they can be moved up and down, once rearranged I need to change the array with the same order of the HTML elements.

**HTML:**

```
     <div id="List">
      <div id="listUnit2" class="row">
       <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
        <p>Orange</p>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div id="listUnit1" class="row">
       <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
        <p>Pear</p>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div id="listUnit0" class="row">
       <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
        <p>Apple</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

**Array:**

```
"listArray": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "apple",
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "pear",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "orange",
  },
]
```

How can I get this result using the `id` value as a reference?

```
"listArray": [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "orange",
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "pear",
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "apple",
  },
]
```

I tried:

```
  var unitsRows = document.querySelectorAll("#list .row");

  var newList = [];

  for (var row of unitsRows) {
    var rowId = row.id
    rowId = rowId.replace('listUnit', "");

    var newEl = listArray[rowId];

    newList.push(newEl);

  }

  listArray = newList;
```

The order of the objects changes but it's not the same of the HTML after some rearrangmet.

Comment: The markup is invalid. _"...after some rearrangmet."_ - So it works with at the beginning? Then there's something else broken -> [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this every time it changes.

I had to fix your invalid markup

```js
const listArray = [...document.querySelectorAll("#List .row")]
  .map(row => ({ id: +row.id.match(/\d+/g), name: row.querySelector('div').textContent.trim() }))

console.log(listArray)
```

```html
<div id="List">
  <div id="listUnit2" class="row">
    <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
      <p>Orange</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="listUnit1" class="row">
    <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
      <p>Pear</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="listUnit0" class="row">
    <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
      <p>Apple</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Your html code is wrong, modify the structure.

2- You have an element with **`id`='List'**, not an element with **`class`=list**. And you need the children of that div, So modify your selector:

```
var unitsRows = document.querySelectorAll("#List .row");
```

3- Get text of `p` element with:

```
let text = document.querySelectorAll(`#${itm.id} p`)[0].textContent.trim();
```

```js
var unitsRows = document.querySelectorAll("#List .row");

let newList = [];

unitsRows.forEach(itm => {
 let text = document.querySelectorAll(`#${itm.id} p`)[0].textContent.trim();
 newList.push({
   id: itm.id.replace('listUnit', ""),
   text
 })
})

console.log(newList)
```

```html
<div id="List">
  <div id="listUnit2" class="row">
    <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
      <p>Orange</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="listUnit1" class="row">
    <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
      <p>Pear</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="listUnit0" class="row">
    <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
      <p>Apple</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you want to get `p` text?? I used the `id` plus the `p` tag: **`#${itm.id} p`** @Artemis

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list on UI, then you sort the `listArray` based on it.

```
listArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  return names.indexOf(a.name) - names.indexOf(b.name);
});
```

I updated your code and print the result in the console. You can check it:

```js
var listArray = new Array({
  "id": 0,
  "name": "apple",
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "pear",
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "orange",
});

var unitsRows = document.querySelectorAll(".row p");
var names = [];
[].forEach.call(unitsRows, function(item) {
  names.push(item.innerHTML.toLowerCase());
});
listArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  return names.indexOf(a.name) - names.indexOf(b.name);
});
console.log('Result', listArray);
```

```html
<div id="List">
  <div id="listUnit2" class="row">
    <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
      <p>Orange</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="listUnit1" class="row">
  <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
    <p>Pear</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="listUnit0" class="row">
  <div class="text-center" style="width:50px;">
    <p>Apple</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```